# Regex to validate URI path with wildcard

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to validate entered URI path with wildcard pattern in a form of asterisks single(*) or double (**). For example: `/path1/*/path2/` or `/path1/path2/**/path3`

I came up with regexp `^(?:\/\w+\/?|\/\*\/?|\/\*\*\/?)+$` that matches all valid path from the list below except: `/foo*` and `/foo**` and does not match invalid except one `/foo//bar`

Could you suggest a better regex to cover all cases and maybe more optimized than my.

https://regex101.com/r/U65utY/1

Considering valid path like:

- /foo/bar
- /foo/bar/
- /*
- /foo/*
- /foo/*/bar
- /foo*
- /**
- /foo**
- /foo/**
- /foo/**/bar

and invalid path like:

- foo
- foo/bar
- //foo
- /foo//bar
- /foo/***/bar
- /***

Comment: Try `^(?:/(?:\*{1,2}|\w+\*{0,2}))+/?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/093wAl/1)

Comment: Or [`^(?:/(?!/)\w*\*{0,2})+$`](https://regex101.com/r/8dPqsi/1)

Comment: Small note: You do not need to escape forward slashes - they have no special meaning. ie your regex `^(?:\/\w+\/?|\/\*\/?|\/\*\*\/?)+$` is identical to `^(?:/\w+/?|/\*/?|/\*\*/?)+$`. Although some languages/tools *delimit* regex with slashes, that does not make the escaping of slashes required in that context part of the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?:/(?:\*{1,2}|\w+\*{0,2}))+/?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/093wAl/1)

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:/(?:\*{1,2}|\w+\*{0,2}))+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `(?:\*{1,2}|\w+\*{0,2})` - one of the alternatives:

    - `\*{1,2}|` - one or two asterisks, or
    - `\w+\*{0,2}` - one or more word chars and then zero, one or two asterisks
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.